# How do I change the hierarchy parent of an activity?

Tags: java, android, class-hierarchy

At the moment it is main activity but I want to change it to the Categories activity.
Is this where the problem lies?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: When I am in a category activity e.g. sport, i want to go back to the categories activity and not the main activity which is the launch activity

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to `AndroidManifest.xml`, find your Sport activity and add this code

```
<activity android:name="Sport" >
    <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
       android:value="PARENT_ACTIVITY_PATH" />
</activity>
```

Substitute `PARENT_ACTIVITY_PATH` with the name of your parent activity adding also your package name (e.g. com.example.Categories).

Answer (score 0):

Going off @Mangusto. After adding the parent activity path to your AndroidManifest add this line in the onCreate method of your Sport activity             `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`